# Are edits from the Help and Improvement queue supposed to override pending suggested edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, help-improvement

This concerns: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21667381

My edit was pending for >45 minutes, then it was rejected ("This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit") after a 2k+ user made another edit. According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53741679/timeline), this subsequent edit was made from the Help and Improvement queue.

Is it expected/desired behaviour to have H&I edits override pending suggested edits?

Comment: We are, and we cannot make an edit ourselves while an suggested edit is pending. Something seems to have gone wrong here.

Comment: on the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53741679/timeline) it looks like it was edited from the help and improvement queue, maybe that bypasses restrictions on pending edits?

Comment: Perhaps they clicked edit and went to grab a coffee, go for a shower and have lunch, then finished it when they returned?

Comment: Well, they can hit "Reject and edit" and then their own edit goes through immediately, but I'm not sure if that causes the message "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

Comment: Done. It could be intended behaviour, but my problem with that is that a good suggested edit could be lost that way and replaced by a less good H&I edit.

Comment: I noticed this before (but I didn't get around to reporting it). In the case I saw, the edit was pending for like 4 hours and then it was rejected. I think this is a bug.

Comment: If I'm following the timeline correctly, you proposed your edit while the question was in the H&I queue.  The whole point of that queue is to get the question edited, so I don't find it at all surprising that an edit submitted there gets applied despite a separate suggested edit being pending.  That having happened, I see no alternative but to reject the pending edit, just as in fact was done.  I think this is just a risk of proposing edits (as opposed to editing when you have the rep to skip review).

Comment: It seems like a technical feature, but those rejected edits (which are *conflicts with a subsequent edit*) make common stat of user's suggestions looking very sad. Personally, I have 3 rejected suggestions and 2 of them are by the same reason as OP had. Now when I suggest something, I can see string *... and 3 edit suggestions rejected*. Why system can't marks those rejections as *rejected by system* or something else? I think when someone is inspecting my suggestion he/she could look at my stat and decides: "Well, this man has lots of rejected suggestions. Get one more now!". Very sad issue..

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if suggested edits were visible in the H&I queue? The H&I queue could tell the reviewer something like "hey, there is already a suggested edit for this question: ... (approve) (approve and edit) (reject)" (and if the reviewer hits reject he gets the opportunity to edit it himself)

Comment: It's certainly still a thing. I regularly got lengthy suggested edits rejected by community for near-identical edits before I got over 2000 reputation and it's quite annoying. I've just tested it on by looking for a ticket in the Help and Improvement queue that had a trivial edit pending. I couldn't see it in the queue, and by making a trivial change, it has now summarily rejected the suggested edit. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25407033 It doesn't make sense why H&I queue reviewers can't be shown existing pending edits to avoid arbitrarily rejecting the efforts of others.

Comment: @DavidBuck TBF, a user can override a suggested edit an *any* time, it doesn't have to be in the H&I queue, they just need to navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postid>/edit`

Comment: @NickA I understand that, but I assume the points discussed above is that H&I reviewers are generally making their edits this oblivious to the presence of a suggested edit. Whilst there's a lot of questions in the H&I queue that are impossible to 'help', some can be assisted with some rigorous editing, but it's a waste of time if someone else has already has a good pending edit, and frustrating for them when community rejects it.